# Used ndiswrapper to install wifi card windows driver but now it says "No Wi-fi Adapter Found"

Tags: drivers, wireless

My Asus X550CC laptop has had some issues with my university Wi-fi - I could only stay connected for 15min and then would crashed and I couldn't get it back on without rebooting. So I went to the IT department and they said to install older drivers and pointed me to this website: https://www.ath-drivers.eu/download-driver-for-Atheros-chipset-with-id-60-and-Windows10-64bit.html

And so I did it when I had Windows and it was okay. But now I installed Ubuntu and tried to do the same thing with ndiswrapper.

When I installed the first time it seemed okay so I rebooted but when it came back on I had no Wi-fi and it said "No Wi-fi Adapter Found".

So I unistalled with "sudo ndiswrapper -r athw10x.inf" and reinstalled with "ndiswrapper -i athw10x.inf" and it gave multiple "installation may be incomplete | couldn't find section "MCCStaTputAdjust.reg" ".

And now when I do "ndiswrapper -l" it outputs "athw10x: invalid driver!".

What should I do now? Can I resolve the issue and still use this driver?

If not, how do I revert it back to an older driver? I got internet connection now by ethernet cable. Already did apt-get update.

My wifi card is the AR9485.

pls help

PS: I got an old broken Samsung laptop. In last recourse can I just change the wifi card and pray those drivers are easier to install?

Edit: Rebooting solved the problem. But how can I install that driver to use wifi in my univ?

Also output to "lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list" was:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AW-NE186H [1a3b:1186]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k, wl
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Ndiswrapper was a blatantly wrong solution.

Comment: You need to uninstall `ndiswrapper`. How did you install it?

Comment: `sudo apt purge 'ndiswrapper.*'` should do it if you installed it with apt.

Comment: Okay I did that. And ndiswrapper is unistalled.

Comment: So your wireless should work after a reboot.

Comment: but now i got no wifi drivers? The icon doesnt show up and "No Wi-fi Adapter Found" is still showing

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Edit updated and my Ubuntu is 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: It looks good. Should work

Comment: But you don't need `wl`. Run `sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source`